# HTML code messing following URLs

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 for an MVC web app using code first method with EF 5.0.
I have written the following code to make a modal window appear at some point:

```
<div id="mod" style="display:none;">
    <div id="mod-container">  
        <div id="mod-close"><img src="~/Content/icons/close.png" title="close" onclick="$('#mod').fadeOut();"/></div>   
        <div id="mod-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If works fine, exept that the image `<img src="~/Content/icons/close.png" [...] />` cannot be found by the browser which thinks its URL is

```
http://localhost:49895/Class1/Home/~/Content/icons/close.png
```

To be precise, every code **under** my div's got broken URL. If I put my image above the div's it's displaying correctly with the following URL:

```
http://localhost:49895/Content/icons/edit.png
```

Do you have an idea where i messed things up?

Edit2: example (after problem being resolved)

This works:

```
<img src="~/Content/icons/close.png" title="close" onclick="$('#mod').fadeOut();"/>
<!-- comment containing a quote ' -->
<div id="mod" style="display:none;">
    <div id="mod-container">  
        <div id="mod-close"></div>   
        <div id="mod-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<!-- comment containing a quote ' -->
<div id="mod" style="display:none;">
    <div id="mod-container">  
        <div id="mod-close"></div>   
        <div id="mod-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<img src="~/Content/icons/close.png" title="close" onclick="$('#mod').fadeOut();"/>
```

Comment: Are you using ajax to call your modal ?

Comment: @Arno2501 No i'm not, it has nothing to do with it actually. The modal is called via another js script down below but deleting it hasn't changed anything

Comment: Are you copy/pasting the example code or typing it manually?

Comment: @Betty i've copy pasted my example codes as they are in my file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a bug in the new Razor 2.0 tilde parsing, or you've mucked up your html by missing a quotation mark or something.  Try using the more explicit way of resolving urls

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/icons/close.png")" />
```

If that works then it suggests a razor bug, if it doesn't then your html is probably broken somehow but the extra @ symbol may be enough for the parser to kick in and tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Edited your answer: I had a comment that the parser did not seem to like

Comment: Can you add the comment to your example for peoples future reference?

Comment: done for some reason my edit to your answer has vanished, so it was a parsing error but using `@Url.Content` is the best way

Comment: your score probably isn't high enough to edit others answers without it being reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

`~` is an asp code element, not HTML. As such it doesn't get rendered by the HTML.

Try wrapping your src with `@Url.Content`

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/icons/close.png")" />
```

Comment: It's actually a new feature of Razor 2.0 - http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-the-new-tilde-slash-feature-in-razor-2

Comment: @Betty Interesting, thanks. Your answer is probably right but are we sure that the OP is using Razor 2?

Comment: Using VS2012, so the chances are very high.  Also considering the tilde replacement works before the div in question I have no doubt.